# Experimental Design and Measuring a Rate of Success

Tags: experiment-design

Suppose you create an experiment for baseball players where you assign an extra batting coach (treatment) to a group of players and then use a control group of players who did not get the extra batting coach.  If I want to know what the impact on the batting average was, what would be the best way to measure this?  Note that baseball players sometimes get injured or get sent to the minors, so they may come and go throughout the season.  I'm not sure if that changes this or not.

1) Would I just look at the total hits divided by the total at-bats for every players in the treatment group and then compare that to the control group?
2) Would I need to find the individual batting averages of each player and then somehow find the average of that and compare across groups?

I have been researching how to measure something like this that makes the most sense and have been unable to find anything that addresses this.  Forgive me if I am missing something obvious!